Select specific task in Azure DevOps UI pipeline run
I try to edit my pipeline to have an multi-select option for tasks in Azure DevOps UI. I created template to install ansible playbook:
parameters:
  - name: Path
    type: string
    default: ''

  - name: extraVars
    type: string
    default: ''

  - name: targetDir
    type: string
    default: ''

  - name: taskTag
    type: string
    default: 'all'

steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Playbook'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        cd ${{ parameters.targetDir }}
        ansible-playbook \
          ${{ parameters.Path }} \
          --extra-vars '{"user_prompt": {"user_input": "${{ parameters.extraVars }}"}}' \
          --tags "${{ parameters.taskTag }}" \

I edited my main pipeline like that:
# Rest of the code
  - name: taskTag
    displayName: 'Select Task'
    type: string
    default: 'all'
    values:
      - all
      - prechecks
      - user_create
      - group_create
      - security_set

Now when I start my pipeline I am able to choose only one specific tasks based on tasks from the ansible playbook. Is it possible to change that list to multi-select list?

You can:

Use an array parameter
Use boolean parameters

Use an array parameter
Changing the taskTag parameter to type: object allows you to set the default value to a string array containing all tasks that can be deployed:
parameters:
  - name: taskTag
    displayName: 'Select Task'
    type: object
    default: 
      - prechecks
      - user_create
      - group_create
      - security_set

steps:
  - checkout: none

  - ${{ each taskTag in parameters.taskTag }}:
    - script: echo ${{ taskTag }}
      displayName: 'Run ${{ taskTag }}'

When queuing a new build all options will be available:

Users can choose which tasks to deploy by removing elements in the array:

The downside of this approach is that users can edit the field and put invalid options or an invalid YAML array, which can break the build.
Use boolean parameters
Use a boolean parameter for each task:
parameters:
  - name: deployPrechecks
    displayName: 'Deploy Prechecks task'
    type: boolean
    default: true
  
  - name: deployUserCreate
    displayName: 'Deploy User Create task'
    type: boolean
    default: true
  
  - name: deployGroupCreate
    displayName: 'Deploy Group Create task'
    type: boolean
    default: true
  
  - name: deploySecuritySet
    displayName: 'Deploy Security Set task'
    type: boolean
    default: true

steps:
  # ...
  - template: templates/run-playbook-steps.yaml
    parameters:
      playbooks: 
        - ${{ if parameters.deployPrechecks }}: 
            - prechecks
        - ${{ if parameters.deployUserCreate }}:
            - user_create
        - ${{ if parameters.deployGroupCreate }}:
            - group_create
        - ${{ if parameters.deploySecuritySet }}:
            - security_set

templates/run-playbook-steps.yaml:
parameters:
  - name: playbooks
    displayName: 'Playbooks'
    type: object
    default: []

steps:
  - ${{ each playbook in parameters.playbooks }}:
    - script: |
        echo Running playbook ${{ playbook }}
      displayName: 'Run playbook: ${{ playbook }}'

Queuing a new pipeline:


Thank you, works as expected with boolean parameters.
